# The amount of time since the system was last booted

Tags: bash, proc, uptime

I have used both `uptime` and `cat /proc/uptime` commands. I know the idle time in the later can be greater than running time (multiprocessors). However, when I add both running and idle times, and compare it to the `uptime` (5:30 hrs) they are not equal. I assume it's because the `uptime` returns the real time and the `cat /proc/uptime` returns processor(s) time.

Short things clear, I want to know the reason exactly and I want to know which one to choose, according to the topic.

Also, is it possible to get the processor(s) time in the last **24 hours?**

**NOTE:** Please read this [article](http://www.helicontech.co.il/?id=linuxcpuload) to understand where this is going.

*Distributor ID:    Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise
*

Comment: The first field of `/proc/uptime` is the uptime in wall time. Meaning it's real time, not CPU time. If that doesn't match the value of `uptime`, then you've got some voodoo going on. Can you provide the output of each for us to look at?

Comment: `uptime`: 21:24 ..`cat \proc\uptime`: 77098.74 103113.16. They are slightly different though..

Answer (score 10):

The `uptime` command reads the two values out of `/proc/uptime`, actually. The first value is the amount of time since the machine booted. The second value, however, is the sum of time that each cpu has not had a runnable process to schedule.

Check out [fs/proc/uptime.c](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/fs/proc/uptime.c) from the Linux kernel github and you'll see how the `/proc/uptime` file's content is generated.

So, to clearly answer, the amount of seconds+milliseconds since the computer booted is the first value in the output of `cat /proc/uptime`.

Comment: For example, a largely idle server I have access to has a /proc/uptime contents of "9843159.39 117450954.76". It has 12 CPUs. You'll notice that the second value divided by the first, equals 11.9322 which means I've had a little shy of 12 processors totally idle for the past 2,700 hours.

Comment: No offense, but can you rephrase what you said? How could this answer my question?

Comment: So the first value is equal to the 5:30 hrs..? So uptime command excludes the idle time when it gives me time in the format of 5:30?